# How to fix 400 Response Incoming from Microsoft Azure Computer Vision service

Tags: c#, azure, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services, bad-request

I subscribed to [Computer Vision API](https://rapidapi.com/microsoft-azure/api/microsoft-computer-vision) on RapidAPI. When I'm testing the API on the RapidAPI platform, it's working perfectly. But when I'm calling it from my app, it responding 400 Bad request.

How can I fix this problem?

I'm using the RESTSharp library.

**Here's my code -**

```
public static IRestResponse GetClassifiedImageData()
{
    var client = new RestClient("{Client Path}");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "{Rapid API host}");
    request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "{My API key}");
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"url\":\"Image URL\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    return client.Execute(request);
}
```

And if I call asyncronusly, I get this message -

> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.String,ComputerVision.Program+d__2]

**Async Code-**

```
public static async Task<IRestResponse> GetClassifiedImageData2()
{
    var client = new RestClient("{Client Path}");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "{Rapid API host}");
    request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "{My API key}");
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"url\":\"Image URL\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    return await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
}
```

I've tried these -

- Restarting Visual Studio.
- Cleaning Temp and prefetch files.

Comment: You have a bad header.  Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the api request with your request.  Then modify your headers to match the api headers.

Comment: Hi! I copied the code from RapidAPI. If I run this, I get this JSON text as a result - "{"code":"NotSupportedVisualFeature","requestId":"*******someID*******","message":"Specified feature type is not valid"}".

Comment: I used postman, it receives this message - {
    "code": "InvalidImageUrl",
    "requestId": "*******someID*******",
    "message": "Image URL is badly formatted."
}

Comment: You have to look at the REQUEST and not the RESPONSE.  The bad response is due to the request.  It looks like the header in the request for "code" is different in Postman and in c#.

Comment: I didn't understand anything. Everything you've said went over my head. :( can you provide me some resources to understand? or can you please elaborate?

Comment: Have you every used a sniffer?  You can download wireshark or fiddler for free from the web.  The sniffer will give the actual messages send over the internet so you can see what was actually sent and received.

Comment: Hi! I installed fiddler and here is a snapshot, I don't understand anything of it.  https://imgur.com/a/pJqUxAa

Comment: The response says has a status of 400 which is a Bad Request.  What does the good request and response look like with the api?  The bad request contains in the post "/analyze?visualfeatures=Categories%252CColor%25CFaces%252CDescription HTTP/1.1   The 1.1 indicates chunk mode.  The request also says it will accept a GZIP return.  And user agent is RestSharp which is the type of browser which is often the cause of these issues.

Comment: Seems to be a bug. I got a success by not urlencoding the request path. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my test, it is the URL encoding that is causing the problem.

You may use the code sample from Rapid API website. <del>However, while using `RestClient`, you should not urlencode the urlpath.</del>  The Rapid API engineer may make a mistake here. In most case, a `,` character does not need to be urlencoded. So, you can directly use `https://microsoft-azure-microsoft-computer-vision-v1.p.rapidapi.com/analyze?visualfeatures=Categories,Tags,Color,Faces,Description` as the path string.

And, anyway, the correct encoded string is `https://microsoft-azure-microsoft-computer-vision-v1.p.rapidapi.com/analyze?visualfeatures=Categories%2cTags%2cColor%2cFaces%2cDescription`

The code sample from Rapid API:
[image]

I used the sample, and got the same error message as yours. But I solved it by using the original string or the correct encoded string:

```
public static async Task<IRestResponse> GetClassifiedImageDataAsync()
{
    // The correct encoded string will work
    //var client = new RestClient("https://microsoft-azure-microsoft-computer-vision-v1.p.rapidapi.com/analyze?visualfeatures=Categories%2cTags%2cColor%2cFaces%2cDescription");

    // The original string will work 
    var client = new RestClient("https://microsoft-azure-microsoft-computer-vision-v1.p.rapidapi.com/analyze?visualfeatures=Categories,Tags,Color,Faces,Description");

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "microsoft-azure-microsoft-computer-vision-v1.p.rapidapi.com");
    request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "71a69********************************3ddb");
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"url\":\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/Kanye_West_at_the_2009_Tribeca_Film_Festival.jpg\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    return await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = GetClassifiedImageDataAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Console.WriteLine(result.Content);
}
```

And you can also use `RestClient`'s method to add query string:

```
public static async Task<IRestResponse> GetClassifiedImageDataAsync()
{
    // Without query string
    var client = new RestClient("https://microsoft-azure-microsoft-computer-vision-v1.p.rapidapi.com/analyze");

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

    // Add as query string manually
    request.AddParameter("visualfeatures", "Categories,Tags,Color,Faces,Description", ParameterType.QueryString);

    request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "microsoft-azure-microsoft-computer-vision-v1.p.rapidapi.com");
    request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "71a69********************************3ddb");
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"url\":\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/Kanye_West_at_the_2009_Tribeca_Film_Festival.jpg\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    return await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
}
```

And the successful result:

[image]

Comment: `,` will be encoded as `%2c`, however, it seems that Repaid API engineer encoded the `%` character again. `%` will be encoded as `%25`. So, you get the strange string  `%252c`

Comment: @MahmudulHasan Have you tried my solution? Is it helpful?